# Possibility to change a String into code-text?

Tags: swift, xcode, function, parameters

I'm just searching for a possibility to change the func parameter (string) into Code-Text. Here's my function:

I want to create a function which can open a new ViewController without writing 100 new function. So when I call the function, there's a parameter given: the tap name/viewcontrollername as a String. How can I change this String into normal code-text?

```
func openNewTap(tapname: String) {
    let tapadress = \(tapname)ViewController()
    let vc = tapadress
    vc.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
    present(vc, animated: true)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no `eval` for Swift code. You cannot pass a string and have Swift respond by turning that into a *type* — e.g., you cannot magically get from `"MyCool"` to MyCoolViewController. A type name must be explicit; it cannot be constructed dynamically. (If you really needed that sort of thing, you would be using Objective-C instead of Swift.)

If the goal is to make this method operate per view controller, then pass a view controller into it, not a string.

Or you could pass a view controller type (e.g. `MyCoolViewController.self`) where a type is expected; for instance, you could use a simple generic:

```
func openNewTap<V: UIViewController>(type v: V.Type) {
    let vc = v.init()
    vc.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
    present(vc, animated: true)
}
```

And call it like this:

```
openNewTap(type: MyCoolViewController.self)
```

But you cannot construct the actual phrase `MyCoolViewController.self` programmatically.